# Possible to capture a scenario example in a BeforeScenario hook?

Tags: specflow

I have a component I'm initializing in a `BeforeScenario` hook.  I'd really like to initialize that component depending on a scenario example value, such as [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines):

```
  Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |
    |  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

..I'd love to pull out the value of, say 'eat' on a per-example basis in the scenario hook and use it to determine what to do.  Is this at all possible in specflow?

Answer (score 0):

A roundabout way of doing this would be accessing it from the SpecFlowContext.Current.ScenarionInfo.Title. When you run the above example, you'd have noticed that the Scenario title generated for each example on the fly is 
`"eating(12, 5,7,null)".` [No idea why the null shows up, but it just does - for version 1.9]

You could potentially parse that title, split it up etc and get the values.